# Attribute Routing Inheritance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, attributerouting

I always used this approach in my MVC applications before

```
[Route("admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller
{

}

[Route("products")]
public class ProductsAdminController :AdminController
{ 
    [Route("list")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

**Url.RouteUrl()** for **Index** action returned **/admin/products/list/**

Now in .NET Core it ignores base class route attribute and result is just **/products/list/**
Is this new to .NET Core? Is there any setup so system can combine **action + controller + base-controller** routes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find a way to combine **action + controller + base-controller** *automatically*, but it is possible to achieve what you're looking for like this:

```
[Route("admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller { }

public class ProductsAdminController : AdminController
{ 
    [Route("products/list")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This approach ends up generating a URL of `/admin/products/list`, with the obvious downside that `products` is something that needs to be repeated for each action. This might be an acceptable compromise; that's up to you to decide. You could make it a *bit* better with a constant, like this:

```
private const string RoutePrefix = "products";

[Route(RoutePrefix + "/list")]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ...
}
```

It's not pretty as it's just a workaround, but worth considering if you don't want to go with [Chris Pratt's Areas suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52335890/2630078).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, that never would have worked. You could use *areas*, and by applying the `[Area]` attribute to the base controller, you'd get the result you describe:

```
[Area("admin")]
public class AdminController : Controller

[Route("products")]
public class ProductsAdminController : AdminController
```

The same would work in Core, as well.

Comment: Well, you have to actually set up your app to utilize areas. They aren't enabled by default. You also need to specify the area during route generation. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Thanks Chris. I looked into the documentation you linked to me, looks like this suppose to work, but this is too much headache for setups and publishing. @Kirk Larkin's answer might be more acceptable, for me but I still appreciate your attention.

Comment: @ChrisPratt is there a way to custom route to areas? Lets say actual area name is admin but I want the area to be reached by /administration/? Otherwise this would be the downside of this option as custom route wont be possible.

Answer (score -1):

Anyone still looking for a way to define "baseURL/ControllerName" in .Net core 3.1.
You would need to define RouteAttribute on your base controller like this:

```
[Route("admin/[controller]")]
```

Note `[controller]` would allow the routing to automatically take the controller name in child class.

Comment: wrong answer, does not work